# How to continue a line with a % sign in it

Tags: matlab, coding-style

Consider the following code:

```
data = textscan(fid,'%s%d%d%d%d%f%d%f%f%f%d','Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',28)
```

I want to break the line as follows:

```
data = textscan(fid,'%s%d%d%d%d%f%d...
%f%f%f%d','Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',28)
```

Matlab does not allow this and makes the second line a comment because of the `%` sign.

I have tried the following:

```
data = textscan(fid,'%s%d%d%d%d%f%d%...
f%f%f%d','Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',28)
```

But now the second line still gets commented out after the first `f`.

How can I do a line continuation with a `%` sign involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use square-brackets (`[]`) to break strings up like that:

```
data = textscan(fid,['%s%d%d%d%d%f%d%f' ...
'%f%f%d'], 'Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',28)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an aside, an often overlooked piece of MATLAB syntax is that the `...` line continuation marker also opens a comment to the end of the line, i.e.

```
x = [ 1, 2, 3, ... This is a comment
      4, 5, 6 ]; %
assert(isequal(x, 1:6))
```